# Why is my program ignoring else statement

Tags: java

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 
public class New {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name... ");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi, "+name);

        int age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your age... "));

        if(age>=18) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome!");}
        else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are not an adult!");
        System.exit(0);}

        String day = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's the day? ");
        if(day == "Monday") { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome back to school!");}
        else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Come back later!");}

    }

}
```

It always gives a "Come back later" message and totally ignoring the "if" -I'm a very beginner, this code is from a tutorial on youtube, tried to edit and I faced this problem-

Comment: In java you cannot compare two strings with `==` you should use `str.equals()` to check for the equality. The condition `day == "Monday"` always returns true. hence, your program is not going to the else statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator doesn't check whether the values are equal in a String, it does the reference comparison (address comparison)

use:

```
if(day.equals("Monday"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic mistake of trying to compare `String`s in java with `==`. You need to use `.equals()` so do `if(day.equals("Monday"))`

https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java